# Reverse Order List in RecyclerView AlertDialog

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a little trouble using an ArrayList for a RecyclerView adapter.

I have a list of players with an AlertDialog to change the number of each one.

The players are updated and sorted correctly, but when I use the button to change the numbers, the list of players appears in reverse order.

If I debug, the "i" value is updated correctly, but after in the AlertDialog starts for the last player and I don't understant what I'm doing wrong.

An example may be:

John (1), Ann (2), Marie (3)

When I ask to change the numbers, the AlertDialog appears in this order:

Marie, Ann, John

The code is like below:

```
private void setOnClickButtons(){
    Button segonaE = findViewById(R.id.se);
    segonaE.setOnClickListener(v -> changeNumbers());
}

private void changeNumbers() {

    for(int i=0;i<workList.size()-2;i++){
        getNumber(i,workList.get(i).toString());
    }

}

private void getNumber(final int position,final String name) {

    final EditText number = new EditText(this);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Numero de "+name)
            .setMessage("Write new Number")
            .setView(number)
            .setPositiveButton("Escollir", (dialog, whichButton) -> {
                String newNumber = number.getText().toString();
                workList.get(position).setNumero(Integer.valueOf(newNumber));
                workList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Player::getNumber));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            })
            .show();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to reverse your for loop to get the right order.

```
for(int i=workList.size()-3;i>=0;i--){
    getNumber(i,workList.get(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem!

In addition, I need to put a "if" to sort the list only when position is the last value of the list, otherwise the "for" not work as I expected.